# count and display the number of clicks on a label using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, counter

I want to count and display the number of clicks on a label using PowerShell in a graphical user interface (GUI).
This is my script:

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create form
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Click Counter"
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(300,150)

# Create label
$label = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Text = "Click Count: 0"
$label.AutoSize = $true
$label.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(20,20)

# Create button
$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Text = "Click Me"
$button.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(20,60)


$button.Add_Click({
    $clickCount++
    $label.Text = "Click Count: $clickCount"
})

# Add controls to the form
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Controls.Add($button)

# Initialize click count
$clickCount = 0

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog()
```

but the problem that i can't increament the number in label and it s fixed in number "1"

Comment: In short: Event handlers run in a _child scope_ of the caller, so in order to create or update variables in the caller's scope, the latter must be targeted explicitly, typically with `$script:variable = ...`; without that, you'll implicitly create a _block-local_ variable.
See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increment your counter variable using the [`script:` scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.4#scope-modifiers) otherwise a new `$clickCount` variable is declared and incremented in the event handler scope and its value is lost as soon as the event completes:

```
$clickCount = 0
$button.Add_Click({
    $script:clickCount++
    $label.Text = "Click Count: $clickCount"
})
```

Another alternative is to use a reference type, for example an array:

```
$clickCount = @(0)
$button.Add_Click({
    $clickCount[0]++
    $label.Text = "Click Count: $clickCount"
})
```